# TTask in Delphi 10.2

Tags: multithreading, delphi

not used TTask before and its a simple thing im trying to do.

While the main form executes a procedure (DoAnalyse) id like to display the TActivityIndicator on my main form without it slowing as the thread does the work. I used to use a progress bar but would prefer to use the more modern Activity Indicator.

I Have tried it two ways:

A simple:

Ttask.Run(DoAnalyse);

and

Task := TTask.Create( procedure
    begin
        DoAnalyse;
    end);
Task.Start;

it executes perfectly and my activity indicator behaves smoothly.

Problem is when the procedure is finished the main form is locked and doesn't respond at all. im guessing I have to put some kind of call back to the main thread but cant find out how to do it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Provide [mcve] please

Comment: Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, read [the Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You'll also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TTask` doesn't have an event when it stops running. Your task procedure needs to use `TThread.Synchronize()` or `TThread.Queue()` (or any other inter-thread mechanism of your choosing) to notify the main thread before it exits.

Otherwise, use `TThread` instead of `TTask`. `TThread` has an `OnTerminate` event.

Comment: Many thanks, by calling a TThreadSynchonize at the end of the thread, it now works perfectly.